# Was the reasoning behind the large tx extra in minergate's transactions ever revealed?

Tags: blockchain, transaction-data, miners, tx-extra

It's absolutely enormous. Was it revealed why it's used?

This is a Minergate block:

http://explore.moneroworld.com/tx/bba343e5e172f07f623fb34c0cbd26519567cc374c5d61d468d370714f3d5b66

This is a regular pool block: http://explore.moneroworld.com/tx/7cddf2da09ec9c890d14ad18b9df7d4cd88e96103a739760a06dc5f91541ba05

Notice in the Minergate block there is this huge tx extra thing: 01c4230d59c83b3042fd82999cfda5be6b77c1673d9442d1f21c7ab9215bdc6c18021198414900000000000000000000000000000321004bff195014248ae22838853bcf293b8945f9baaac693c2d05bafe2f0f3e6c69e

Comment: Could you supply an example ?

Comment: @user36303 added

Comment: I was thrown off by the "enormous", I thought you had found something else :) I added a partial answer.

Comment: @user36303 whoops sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra payload appears to be for merged mining, as per the definitions in src/cryptonote_basic/tx_extra.h:

`field 0: extra pub key: <c4230d59c83b3042fd82999cfda5be6b77c1673d9442d1f21c7ab9215bdc6c18>
field 1: extra nonce: 9841490000000000000000000000000000
field 2: extra merge mining tag: depth 0, merkle root <4bff195014248ae22838853bcf293b8945f9baaac693c2d05bafe2f0f3e6c69e>`

I believe XDN was switching to merge mining with Monero, so it could be this. XDN was abandoned a year ago though. Fantomcoin was also merged mined, but has been dead even longer.